# How to dynamically change button style using forums react?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, button, background-color

I want the user to type in the color of the button and have it change dynamically to whatever the user types.
I'm still new to react and trying to figure things out.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("white");

  function handleChange(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    setName(event.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>{name}</h1>
      <input
        onChange={handleChange}
        type="text"
        placeholder="What's your name?"
      />

      <button type="text" style={{ backgroundColor: { name } }}>
        Submit
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `backgroudColor` property should be set to a `string` (just `name`) instead of an object (`{ name }`)

So this

```html
<button type="text" style={{ backgroundColor: { name } }}>
  Submit
</button>
```

Should be this

```html
<button type="text" style={{ backgroundColor: name }}>
  Submit
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the brackets like:
`style={{ backgroundColor: name  }}`